# Are there any open source mapping APIs/toolkits for drawing axes,labels,graticules etc?

Tags: open-source-gis

I tried to post a more generic question to meta, but it's my first question, so I didn't have a reputation yet.

The first question I have is whether this is an appropriate place to ask questions about the availability of software "components"--APIs or toolkits for mapping and geographic/geodetic functions.

If this is the appropriate place:  I would very much like to find an open source mapping API, using either OpenGL or one of the QT graphics APIs like QPaint--something that draws and labels axes and graticules, scales, etc--if it had geographic entry points (lat, long) so much the better.  Map underlays would be wonderful.

I have not been able to find anything despite repeated searches, so have written a good deal of my own, using C++/QT/OpenGL.  But I find I am spending as much time on my infrastructure as I am on my application, and I'd like to get out of that situation if possible.

My application is typically real-time plotting of positions of underwater vehicles and associated data.

Comment: I think this is the perfect forum for this kind of question.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like QGIS API could be what you're looking for. It's written in C++ and Qt-based. API docs are here: http://doc.qgis.org/. This API enables you to load all kinds of geodata for your background map, you can label features, etc.

There's also a [guide on developing your own applications based on QGIS API](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Developers_Corner#Help_on_writing_custom_apps_with_QGIS_API).

As your use case is tracking of vehicles, you might also be interested in the code of [QGIS GPS Tracker](http://www.mappinggeek.ca/QGISPythonPlugins/trackgps/TheQGISGPSTrackerPlugin.html).

Comment: the QGIS API looks pretty good--I had seen QGIS before, but it had been a while and I didn't realize the API was available.  I'm not sure it does everything I want, but I'll check it out further.

Many of the other suggestions referred to Java API's and the like--unless they have a C++ binding, they won't save me any time.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/). It is a great tool to create maps and map layers. It has a nice Pythonic interface ([tutorial](http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/GettingStarted)), and it is being widely used. One of the most famous users is [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/):

> Mapnik is the software we use to
>   render the main Slippy Map layer for
>   OSM, along with other layers such as
>   the "cycle map" layer and "noname"
>   layer.

An impressive example from their flickr photostream:
[image]

Comment: Mapnik looks pretty good--what I don't see, however, is axes and graticules.  Perhaps I don't know the right search terms to find those things--there are lots of mapping toolkits around, but very few put map scales, axes, tics, and other cartographic elements on the map--for my application, where we frequently work in the open ocean, these are vital aids for users to understand the maps

Comment: AFAIK, adding axes and scales is done manually. See this short article for more information: http://www.britishideas.com/2009/09/22/map-scales-and-printing-with-mapnik/